# How to solve $\sin^{-1}(x)=\sin^{-1}(2/5) +\sin^{-1}(3/5)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to solve this equation:

> $\sin^{-1}(x)=\sin^{-1}(2/5) +\sin^{-1}(3/5)$.

I applied the $\sin$ function on both sides and I've  got

$x=\sin\left(\sin^{-1}( \frac{2}{5}) +\sin^{-1}( \frac{3}{5})\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

$$x=\sin(\sin^{-1}x)=\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\frac25+\sin^{-1}\frac35\right)$$
$$=\sin(\sin^{-1}\frac25)\cos(\sin^{-1}\frac35) +\cos(\sin^{-1}\frac25)\sin(\sin^{-1}\frac35)$$
$$=\frac25\cdot\frac45+\frac{\sqrt{21}}{5}\cdot\frac35$$